# Как сверстать элемент выбора языка на сайте?

Tags: html, jquery, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Верстаю, и наткнулся на следующую проблему, как сверстать выбор языка (просто сверстать, чтобы менялся русский/английский). Делал через select, но проблема в том что в option нельзя добавить изображения. И вот как быть, помогите с советом, как решить данную проблему? Спасибо.

Comment: вы хотите добавить значек флага рядом с текстом?

Comment: `ul li a`​​​​​​​

Comment: да, что бы по умолчанию стоял флаг Рус, а выбрать можно было флаг Eng

Comment: в `option` изображения добавить можно - используйте для этого псевдоэлементы `::before` и`::after` или свойство `background-image`. но, по идее, после выбора оно не будет показано в самом `select`.

Comment: да, в том и дело, что его не будет видно при выборе

Comment: Можешь это все сделать с помощью **bootstrap** http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns

Comment: и как выбранный язык отобразится, он же не запишется в тело кнопки

Comment: ну если надо через `select`, то можно, например, добавлять флаги в `options` через `background`, а потом через `js` вычислять этот `background` у выбранного элемента и присваивать его самому `select`

Comment: да не обязательно через select, просто другого способа я не нашел

Comment: @zorro так вы верстку спрашиваете, а не взаимодействие скриптов, ну отобразился другой язык, все равно страница то не перезагрузилась с новым языком.

Comment: я про верстку, просто чтобы как в select можно было выбрать смену языка но с флагом страны

Comment: @zorro то уже проблема back-end

Comment: @HesusMen это я знаю, но элемент всеравно надо заверстать

Comment: @zorro http://www.bootply.com/110686 вот так пробуй, но с bootstrap  на back-end будет легче

Comment: @HesusMen это не решение, а только намёк и ссылка на него. Ответы - для цельных и самодостаточных решений. Если можете опубликовать в ответе пример кода - будет здорово.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вопрос про верстку, верстается подобным образом.

```css
.dropbtn {
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    width: 140px;
}

.dropbtn
{
  background: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flag-3/16/Russia-Flag-icon.png') no-repeat left center;
  padding-left: 25px;
  width: 40px;
}

.dropbtn::after {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48px-16.png") no-repeat scroll center center;
    content: "";
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 7px;
    width: 16px;
}

.dropdown-content a:first-child
{
  background: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/flag-3/16/Russia-Flag-icon.png') no-repeat left center;
}

.dropdown-content a:last-child
{
  background: url('https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fatcow/farm-fresh/16/flag-usa-icon.png') no-repeat left center;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropbtn">RU</div>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">RU</a>
    <a href="#">EN</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, не ожидал, я просил только совет, а тут еще и код! Респект!

Comment: А как сделать чтобы показывался потом выбранный язык?

Answer (score 4):

Можно и так:

```
<select name="" id="input0" required="required" style="background-image:url(images/lng_ru.png);">
    <option  style="background-image:url(images/lng_ru.png);" value="rus">rus</option>
    <option  style="background-image:url(images/lng_eng.png);" value="eng">eng</option>
</select>

<script>
$('#input0').click(function() {
 if($("select#input0 :selected").val() == "rus") {
    $("select#input0").attr('style', 'background-image:url(images/lng_ru.png);');
 }
 if($("select#input0 :selected").val() == "eng") {
    $("select#input0").attr('style', 'background-image:url(images/lng_eng.png);');
 }
    console.log('select color: '+$("select#input0 :selected").val());
});
</script>
```

Comment: подскажите, почему картинка не добавляется если ее добавить background-image ? вот тут тоже самое говорят, что не работает https://stackoverflow.com/a/2966006/13754729