# Переключатель языков на JQ

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Верстаю панель языков. RU/FR/EN. Пытаюсь сделать чтобы по умолчанию было RU а при наведении появлялся весь список остальных двух. Помогите реализовать это) Если есть примеры прошу ссылку)

Comment: Смотрите [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494548/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5/494564#494564), недавно было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как альтернативу, делал недавно в проекте у себя:

```js
$('.language-select').click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass('open');
})

$('.language-select li').click(function(){
var setLang = $('.language-select').data('location'),
    dataLangSelect = $(this).data('lang')
      $('.language-select').data('location', dataLangSelect);
      $('.language-select li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.language-select {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.language-select li {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #f8b142;
  order: 2;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 40px;
}
.language-select li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #eea634;
}

.language-select.open {
  height: auto;
}

.language-select li.active {
  order: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="language-select"> 
  <li class="active" data-lang="ua">укр</li>
  <li data-lang="ru">рус</li> 
  <li data-lang="en">eng</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Я новичок в JS/JQ, не могли бы вы подсказать как сделать чтобы после выбора языка окошко исчезало?)