# Выбор языка на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Делаю сайт на html без шаблона по такой схеме:

- В корне сайта лежит `index.html` и две папки, `en` и `ru`, с английской и русской версиями сайта соответственно.
- `index.html`, который в корне, у них общий и в него встроен код переключателя языка взятый из [ответа на вопрос «Переключатель языков на JQ»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496433/271104). Этот код работает замечательно/ Я только подключил картинки флагов, вместо текстовых ссылок.

Вот код `index.html`:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>R2FBT amateur radio station</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="amateur, radio, station" />
<meta name="description" content="Home page R2FBT" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="bg">

<div id="main">

<!-- header begins -->

<div id="header">
<ul class="menu-main">
  <li><a href="index.html" class="but_t"  title="">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="biography.html" class="but" title="">BIOGRAPHY</a></li>
  <li><a href="eqipment.html"  class="but" title="">EQIPMENT</a></li>
  <li><a href="qsl.html"  class="but" title="">QSL</a></li>
  <li><a href="logbook.html" class="but" title="">LOGBOOK</a></li>
  <li><a href="dx_cluster.html" class="but" title="">DX CLUSTER</a></li>
  <li><a href="rbn_map.html" class="but" title="">RBN map</a></li>
  <li><a href="rbn_graph.html" class="but" title="">RBN on graph</a></li>
  <li><a href="products.html" class="but" title="">PRODUCTS</a></li>
  <li><a href="contacts.html" class="but" title="">CONTACTS</a></li>
</ul>

<script src="/r2fbt.ru/logbook/js/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<ul class="language-select"> 
  <li class="active" data-lang="en" style="background: url('images/en.png') no-repeat left center;"></li>
 <li data-lang="ru" style="background: url('images/ru.png') no-repeat left center;"></li> 
</ul>

<script>
$('.language-select').click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass('open');
})

$('.language-select li').click(function(){
var setLang = $('.language-select').data('location'),
dataLangSelect = $(this).data('lang')
  $('.language-select').data('location', dataLangSelect);
  $('.language-select li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
</script>
```

**Вопрос** заключается в том, как подключить данный скрипт к сайту, чтобы при выборе например английского языка в меню подставлялся путь к английским страницам:

```
<li><a href="/r2fbt.ru/en/biography.html" class="but" title="">BIOGRAPHY</a></li>
```

а при выборе русского языка — к русским страницам:

```
<li><a href="/r2fbt.ru/ru/biography.html" class="but" title="">BIOGRAPHY</a></li>
```

Comment: именно так никак. делать на php, java и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Решил задачу следующим образом:

```
<?php require_once ('langmem.php'); ?>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Biography R2FBT</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="biography amateur radio station" />
<meta name="description" content="Biography R2FBT" />
<link href="/r2fbt.ru/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="bg">

<div id="main">

<!-- header begins -->

<div id="header">
    <ul class="menu-main">
        <li><a href="/r2fbt.ru/index.php" class="but"  title="">HOME</a>
</li>
      <li><a href="/r2fbt.ru/<?php echo $lang ?>/biography.php" 
class="but_t" title="">BIOGRAPHY</a></li>
       <li><a href="/r2fbt.ru/<?php echo $lang ?>/eqipment.php"  class="but" 
title="">EQIPMENT</a></li>
      <li><a href="/r2fbt.ru/<?php echo $lang ?>/qsl.php"  class="but" 
title="">QSL</a></li>
      <li><a href="/r2fbt.ru/<?php echo $lang ?>/logbook.php" class="but" 
title="">LOGBOOK</a></li>
      <li><a href="/r2fbt.ru/<?php echo $lang ?>/dx_cluster.php" class="but" 
title="">DX CLUSTER</a></li>
      <li><a href="/r2fbt.ru/<?php echo $lang ?>/rbn_map.php" class="but" 
title="">RBN map</a></li>
      <li><a href="/r2fbt.ru/<?php echo $lang ?>/rbn_graph.php" class="but" 
title="">RBN on graph</a></li>
      <li><a href="/r2fbt.ru/<?php echo $lang ?>/products.php" class="but" 
title="">PRODUCTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="/r2fbt.ru/<?php echo $lang ?>/contacts.php" class="but" 
title="">CONTACTS</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<form class="language-select" action="/r2fbt.ru/<?php echo $lang ?
>/biography.php" method="post">
    <input style="background: url('/r2fbt.ru/images/en.png') no-repeat left 
center; height: 30px; width: 60px;" type="submit" name="en" value="" />
    <input style="background: url('/r2fbt.ru/images/ru.png') no-repeat left 
center; height: 30px; width: 60px;" type="submit" name="ru" value="" />
</form>

<!-- header ends -->
.....................................
.....................................
```

langmem.php

```
<?php 
    if (!isset($_session)) session_start();
    $_session['lang'] = 'en';
    if (isset($_POST['ru'])) $_session['lang'] = 'ru';
    $lang = $_session['lang'];
?>
```

Это работает, только с перезагрузкой страницы и что бы переключился язык на флаг нужного языка нужно кликать 2 раза.

Answer (score 0):

Можно положить код языка в куку или localStorage и потом вставлять в ссылки. В такие ссылки можно ложить "шаблон" аля `/r2fbt.ru/---lang---/biography.html` и потом по загрузке страницы заменить шаблон примерно вот так:

```
var lang = 'ru';
$('a').each(function(i, el) {
    el.href = el.href.replace('---lang---', lang);
});
```

Так делать **плохо**, **неправильно** и лучше использовать либо серверную генерацию страниц уже с языком, либо какой-нибудь современный framework аля ReactJS или Angular. Но как временное решение, возможно, подойдет.

Comment: Если вы сами понимаете, что "так делать плохо, неправильно...", то зачем тогда давать такие советы?

Comment: @АлексейФилатов я предоставил костыль, которым можно временно воспользоваться. И предупредил, что это костыль, который должен быть временным